# Create an access_token to get list of events using graph API - android

Tags: android, events, facebook-graph-api

Using the following coding, I can get the JSON response of all events on facebook:

```
 eventsValue = new URL(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAIZBliHWLH30kpzoYtdnOBsvroLhZCrwAFxZBy7fSAnyFNspOU8f5WW9ShVWztHZAcLbsW0tigXpDFJXIR7ZAsfby62zMdqrzgmvfAJUa");

            Log.d("Events Value ", eventsValue.toString());
```

This code works fine and displays all events before the link gets expired.
Problem here is that the link gets expired all the time and I need to hard code.

I would like my program to work without having to hard code the URL all the time.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply: You shouldn't be hard coding an `access_token` - bad practice. Can you explain your requirement for this?

If you're authenticating as a Facebook Application, read the app access_token documentation here, it'll suit your needs a lot more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/

Comment: I went through the link, I found out app ID, secret app ID and grant_type are needed so that those three variables will be concatenated and the access token will be created. After I concatenate all three what I get is something like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=client_id=392736034134808&client_secret=90fc193d7d183e82d71be74078d23375&grant_type=client_credentials
But I require something like:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAPNe8PCac7Xyp3iw17SSNJmZCksOKNYJlkWPFQq0iMPQZAXB1dtqXknoiZCJbT7oUjAWMvYZAvXrcS5ax7IMrHYO4nB0IUE5FzlDJHc7

Comment: I am doing this for an android project